# Как скрыть форму обратного звонка при успешном заполнении?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На сайте есть форма обратного звонка, когда клиент заполняет поля и нажимает на "отправить" то рядом с баттоном появляется слово "Ваш запрос успешно отправлен", но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправить, в той же форме все баттоны исчезали и вместо них выводило "Ваш запрос успешно отправлен"

```
    $json = [
            'status' => 1,
            'text' => _('Ваш запрос успешно отправлен')
        ];
        die(json_encode($json));

    } else {

        $error = [
            'status' => 0,
            'text' => _('Заполните ФИО и Номер телефона')
        ];
        die(json_encode($error));

    }

}
```

ajax код

```
$.ajax({
            url: "../../engine/ajax/eogpo.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                action: 'orderCallWidget',
                phone: $('#phoneWidget').val(),
                FIO: $('#FIOWidget').val(),
                data: $('input, select').serialize()
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#overLoader").show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.status) {
                    $('.product__form__error').html("").hide();
                    $("#successMessage").html(data.text);

                } else {
                    $("#successMessage").html("");
                    $('.product__form__error').html(data.text);
                }
                $("#overLoader").hide();
            },
            error: function() {
                $('.product__form__error').html('<?php echo _("Неизвестная ошибка"); ?>');
                $("#overLoader").hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Это делается на клиенте, php код не требуется.

Comment: @u_mulder как именно делается на клиенте?

Answer (score 0):

Отправляете данные формы по ajax, и в случае успеха в теле success, делаете все что угодно

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:  "request.php",
     data: form.serialize(),
     success: (data) => {
        // Тут ваш код после успешной отправки
     }
}
```

В интернете полно примеров данной реализации.